# How to reference a bundle-image from within a Bundle?

Tags: resources, symfony

I have an image in my bundle at `Bundle/Resources/public/images/abc.png`.

I want to reference it from a template file. My first thought was `<img src="{{ asset('images/abc.png') }}" />` which is obviously not working.

I don't want to have a folder like `Bundle/Resources/public` in the rendered HTML, so is there a way to reference a resource file in a nice way? I couldn't find anything about this in the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `assets:install` command places (or symlinks) all bundle resources under the `web/bundles` directory. The `AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/images/img.png` then placed under `web/bundles/acmedemo/images/img.png` and you can use `asset('bundles/acmedemo/images/img.png')` in your template. This is the "official" way, most bundles use assets this way.

You can write your own asset installing command if you want, see `vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/AssetsInstallCommand.php` or any other solution which places assets under the `web` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the image in the folder you specify in the `asset` method.

```
| app/
| src/
| web/
`-| images/
  `-| abc.png
  | javascript/
  | css/
```

Comment: I want to keep it maintainable and don't have one big image folder with resources from multiple bundles. Is it best practice to do it like that in symfony?

Comment: I can't tell you about best practises, but the folder you pass to the `asset`-method is evaluated from the root of your webdirectory. So, whatever you pass the method will be the folder under the `web` directory symfony searches in.

Comment: I bet that there are other options. I will have to look at some real world bundles, how they reference images.

Comment: @crudolf - If you don't want to copy them, then you can use `--symlink` parameter to `assets:install` command.